# how to call functions independently?

Tags: javascript

I have some functions for validation, and another function named "validation()"  to call all of my validation functions in it. before the form submitted , this function calls and the functions called  run in sequence and when one of them returns false , next function doesn't call. my request is how can I call them independently ?
here is piece of my code:

```
function IsEmail() {
    rows = document.getElementById('txtRows').value.split('#');
    types = document.getElementById('txtTypes').value.split('#');

    var CorrectFormat = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
    msg_req = "";
    var flg = true;

    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        if (types[i] == "email") {
            var ctrl_val = document.getElementById('ctrl-' + i).value;
            if (!CorrectFormat.test(ctrl_val)) {
                msg_req += "invalid format ! \n";
                flg = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (flg)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
        function validations() {
        if (!(required_field()) || !(Is Email())) {
            var  str = "there are some errors :\n";
            if (msg_req != "") {
                str += msg_req;
                alert(str);
            }
            msg_req = "";
            return false;
        }
        else {
            msg_req = "";
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems that those two functions (required_field and isEmail) have the side effect of changing an instance variable called msg_req. I am not too fond of such things, it might be better to append the results to a local variable msg_req and if your first if check if the variable isn't blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is since you are using `||` operator, as soon as one condition returns false and is negated the logical operation becomes true there for javascript engine will not execute further functions.

```
function validations() {
    var valid   = required_field();
    valid = isEmail() && valid;
    if (!valid) {
        var  str = "there are some errors :\n";
        if (msg_req != "") {
            str += msg_req;
            alert(str);
        }
        msg_req = "";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        msg_req = "";
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var requiredBool = required_field();
var isEmailBool = isEmail();

if(!requiredBool  || !isEmailBool ) 
{
 ...
{
```